# Binding to a dictionary and create key

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, data-binding

I try to bind a wpf control to a dicionary entry and if it not exists it should create it.

Here what I already got (as an example, not my real code):

**DataObject:**

```
public class DataObject
{
  public Dictionary<string,object> Values { get; set; }
}
```

**VM:**

```
public class ViewModel : NotificationObject
{
  private DataObject _myObject = new DataObject();

  public DataObject myObject 
  {
    get {return _myObject;}
    set {_myObject = value;}
  }

  public List<string> ValueList
  {
    get {return new List<string>{"Test Item 1","Test Item 2"};}
  }
}
```

**GUI:**

```
<CustomVars:MyTextBox x:Name="MyValue1" Text="{Binding myObject.Values[Item1]}"/>
<CustomVars:MyComboBox x:Name="MyValue2" Text="{Binding myObject.Values[Item2]}" ItemsSource="{Binding ValueList}"/>
....
<CustomControls:Item Text="{Binding ElementName=MyValue1, Path=Text}"/>
<CustomControls:Selection Text="{Binding ElementName=MyValue2, Path=Text}" Items="{Binding ElementName=MyValue2, Path=Items}"/>
```

The item with the key Item2 gets set but not the Item1. Can somebody tell me why?

Thanks, Damon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to put `Mode=TwoWay` in the binding of CustomControls...